# Keep dynamically loaded HTML elements in case the browser "Back" or "Forward" button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

(I read a few threads on the subject but did not find a working solution.)

On my page, I have a "Load more" button that triggers an Ajax call to get new portion of items to display. I would like to preserve these dynamically appended elements when the user gets to different page and then hits "Back" or "Forward" button of the browser - however I cannot get it to work.

I tried setting `cache: true` for the jQuery `$.ajax()` request. I also played around with the "Expires" and "Cache-Control" headers on the request, but no success. I consider keeping the dynamic content in `<input type="hidden">` and listening to `onLoad` event in my jQuery script.

Any advice on how I can keep/cache the appended elements every time they're dynamically loaded?

**UPDATE:**
What I need to "remember" is HTML structure, so possibly a lot of characters (imagine if the user hits "Load more" 10 times and then leaves the page). So the size of any storage needs to be considered.

Comment: You can "remember" your added elements with a cookie

Comment: @kmsdev I posted an update.

Comment: I think one way to do this would be to use local storage to store the new items, each timestamped, when a page loads include the current timestamp to check against, if any newer in local storage include, delete any older.

Comment: If you have a "load more" button, you can know (and save) how many times that button was pressed and trigger your function passing a parameter.

Comment: @DaveJones Interesting concept. I have two concerns, though. The first is that `localStorage` has a fixed size that's different for every browser (generally around 5MB). The second is that I cannot really delete the older results, because I need all of them to be shown every time "Back" button is clicked (and the page still was not reloaded).

Comment: @kmsdev Of course. The idea here is to find a way to store the new data OR make the data cached by a browser.

Comment: The browser does not cache dynamic data, so I think you can use a cookie method (if your button triggers always the same function, a "load more") or use a server side solution.

Comment: @lesssugar 5MB is a lot of data! I am presuming it's only json data. If 'storing' new loads then when a user returns another time, not via the back button, you'll need to 'clean' the storage so a time stamp will be need  to be included on the server side in a 'fresh' page.

Comment: @DaveJones Yes, that's a lot of data, but what do I do if a user presses "Load more" 50 times in a row and `localStorage` size is exceeded? Anyway, worth giving a try, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I commented above. I think, in your case, it is useful. If this way is unviable you should consider to use a server side workaround. [Check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/87gp5es4/).

```
$(function(){

    var clicked_times = 0;

    $('button').on('click', function(){
        // ajax....
        // ajax success:
        clicked_times++;
        $('<p>new content</p>').insertBefore($(this));
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        if( clicked_times > 0 ) Cookies.Set('reload_contents', clicked_times);
    };

    if( Cookies.Check('reload_contents') ){
        var times = Cookies.Get('reload_contents');
        for( var i = 0; i < times; i++){
            $('button').trigger('click');
        }
        Cookies.Set('reload_contents', '', -1);
    }

});

/** Cookie methods */
var Cookies = {

    Check: function (name) {
        return !!this.Get(name);
    },

    Get: function (name) {
        var n, ca, c;
        n = name + "=";
        ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            c = ca[i].trim();
            if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) return c.substring(name.length + 1, c.length);
        }
        return false;
    },

    Set: function (name, value, expire, options) {
        var d = new Date(), expires;
        var defaults = { expire_in: 'days', path: '/' };
        if (typeof options !== "undefined") $.extend(true, defaults, options);
        if (expire !== undefined && expire !== null) {
            if (defaults.expire_in == 'days') d.setDate(d.getDate() + expire);
            else if (defaults.expire_in == 'minutes') d.setDate(d.getTime() + expire * 1000);
            else {
                return false;
            }
            expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        }
        else expires = expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; " + expires + '; path=' + defaults.path;
        return true;
    }

};
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a handy template. Size of the JavaScript cookie is rather small, though. The code above will work for "reasonable" value-lengths, of course.

Comment: Since the code above just stores an integer, you can press the "load more" button some millions of times. The workaround happens when the page is load. We look for how many times the button was pressed and trigger the button that number of times. So.. That's the reason I think it can work for your purpose.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. That's an interesting workaround, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the browsers history. Try that (don't know about its crossbrowser-ability):

```
var url = "http://newurl.com";// you could save only hashes too.
    if (/*url &&*/ location.url != url && history.replaceState) {
        history.replaceState(null, url, url);
    }
```

Greetings. André